# resizing,drag and drop functionality of charts

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple charts in WPF application and we are generating that on runtime.i have implemented drag and drop functionality with resizing of charts in it,currently we have implemented this functionality using Adorners and Thmumbs
but drag and drop functionality is not that much user friendly. I want to implement this functionality as like excel charts  so is there any control in telerik or any other API which can fullfill all this requirements?

Comment: Drag-and-drop of *parts* of charts or *whole* charts from/to *where*?

Comment: I need to drag and drop whole chart.